# Apple TV: Account verification nuisance

Tags: icloud, security, appletv, accounts, verify

My Apple TV keeps nagging me to enter my password for account verification.

When I give it the correct password, it appears to accept it, but will continue to ask for verification.

Verification isn't even actually required, because it gives the option to decline, so it's pointless.

It's easy enough to deal with but it's constantly harrassing me with frequent verification request popups during movies, etc.

Does anyone else have the same problem, or is it an isolated case?
Does anyone have a solution, short of contacting Apple? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what specific verification item is problematic, you might need to reset the Apple TV and make sure your Apple ID and date/time setting work before loading any third party apps or logging into other accounts.

There is a chance you could use Xcode to look over the AppleTV logs and determine what app is triggering the requests, but it might be faster to wipe and verify it’s not software corruption or storage issue.